# UTF-8 output of java program differs if compiled on command line vs. in IntelliJ

Tags: java, command-line, utf-8, intellij-idea, outputstream

The output of the following program differs depending on whether I have IntelliJ compile it, or whether I compile it by hand from the command line.  As far as I can tell, I have only one compiler and JVM on my machine.

```
public class OutputTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
  System.out.println(" Java Version: " +
        System.getProperty("java.version") +
        " from " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
  String message = "Dźien Dobry. Jak się masz?";
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new java.io.BufferedWriter(
        new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(stream, charset)), true);
  pw.write(message);
  pw.close();
  System.out.println(stream.toString());
  System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(stream.toByteArray()));
 }
}
```

Output when compiled in IntelliJ:

```
Java Version: 1.6.0_26 from Apple Inc.
Dźien Dobry. Jak się masz?
[68, -59, -70, 105, 101, 110, 32, 68, 111, 98, 114, 121, 46, 32, 74, 97, 107, 32, 115, 105, -60, -103, 32, 109, 97, 115, 122, 63]
```

Output when compiled from the command line:

```
Java Version: 1.6.0_26 from Apple Inc.
D≈∫ien Dobry. Jak siƒô masz?
[68, -30, -119, -120, -30, -120, -85, 105, 101, 110, 32, 68, 111, 98, 114, 121, 46, 32, 74, 97, 107, 32, 115, 105, -58, -110, -61, -76, 32, 109, 97, 115, 122, 63]
```

To be clear:  The output depends on where the code is compiled. I also see the first answer if I have IntelliJ compile the code, but run it from the command line.

I am running MacOS 10.6.8.

Also, for what it's worth:  When I compile it from the command line in Linux, I get the same answer that the IntelliJ-compiled version gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the platform encoding; you may need to specify the -encoding parameter on the command line to match what IntelliJ is doing. Without it it'll use the default platform encoding, which may or may not match how IntelliJ behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Change default encoding in IntelliJ IDEA `Settings` | `File Encodings`.

Comment: I believe he desires the output compiled by IntelliJ IDEA, and is seeing the wrong output from the javac compiler.  You have the right idea, but he should change the javac command line.

Comment: @EdwinBuck, IntelliJ IDEA uses file encoding setting when compiling and running your application, it transforms this setting to `-Dfile.encoding=<value>` automatically for run and `-encoding` equivalent when compiling. So it makes sense to change this setting globally in IDEA instead of putting compiler and runtime JVM options manually. It will also ensure that the new files are created with the right encoding. My reply is helpful when using IntelliJ IDEA, while @Dave's reply is helpful when building from command line.

Comment: Sounds fine to me, except that with his description of the problem, it sounds like the IntelliJ IDEA Setting is correct, so changing it might induce issues.  (The classes compiled with IntelliJ IDEA present the same string in output as the embedded "input" string).

Comment: IntelliJ was correct.  I was missing the -encoding parameter on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Set javac option to match encoding of file :

```
-encoding encoding
Set the source file encoding name, such as EUC-JP and UTF-8. If -encoding is not specified, the platform default converter is used.
```